# Custom Transition cover StatusBar

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am doing a custom animation for a controller, I want the black background (dimmView) of the controller to cover the status bar, I have tried many options but all my searches have come to nothing, the project can be downloaded from the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J_fOwqD12vRUbzz6qiFFu56RAZAGuGu6/view?usp=sharing)

UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

```
    class PanelTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    private let driver = TransitionDriver()
    
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        driver.link(to: presented)
        let presentationController = DimmPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting ?? source)
        presentationController.driver = driver
        return presentationController
    }
    
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return PresentAnimation()
    }
    
    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return DismissAnimation()
    }
    
    func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return driver
    }
    
    func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return driver
    }
    
 }
```

PresentationController subClass UIPresentationController

```
class DimmPresentationController: PresentationController{
    
    private lazy var dimmView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)
        view.alpha = 0
        return view
    }()
    
    override func containerViewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.containerViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        dimmView.frame = containerView!.frame
    }
    
    override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        super.presentationTransitionWillBegin()
        containerView?.insertSubview(dimmView, at: 0)
        performAlongsideTransitionIfPossible { [unowned self] in
            self.dimmView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
    
    override func presentationTransitionDidEnd(_ completed: Bool) {
        super.presentationTransitionDidEnd(completed)
        if !completed {
            self.dimmView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
        super.dismissalTransitionWillBegin()
        performAlongsideTransitionIfPossible { [unowned self] in
            self.dimmView.alpha = 0
        }
    }

    override func dismissalTransitionDidEnd(_ completed: Bool) {
        super.dismissalTransitionDidEnd(completed)
        if completed {
            self.dimmView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    private func performAlongsideTransitionIfPossible(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        guard let coordinator = self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator else {
            block()
            return
        }

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
            block()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Nothing can actually go on top of the status bar, what you see happening in some apps is a snapshot of the status bar gets taken, placed below the status bar, then the status bar gets hidden without animation and since the snapshot is a UI element you can add other views over it. Once what ever you want to do is done, the snapshot is removed and the status bar gets shown again.